# If $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely , then so does, $\sum \frac {a_n^2} {1+a_n^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely , then so does, $\sum \dfrac {a_n^2} {1+a_n^2}$

**Attempt:** Given that $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely $\implies \sum |a_n|$ converges.

$\implies|a_n|<M_~~\forall~n\in \mathbb N $

$\implies |a_n|.|a_n|<M.|a_n|$

$\implies \sum|a_n|.|a_n|<M.\sum|a_n|$

$\implies \sum a_n^2 <M M'$ where $\sum|a_n|<M'$

$\implies \sum a_n^2$ is bounded and hence convergent.

Let $\sum a_n^2 < A$, then, $\sum \dfrac {a_n^2}{1+a_n^2} < A$

Hence, $\sum \dfrac {a_n^2}{1+a_n^2}$ is convergent.

Is my attempt correct?

Thank you for reading through!

Comment: Looks fine. Not *quite* the way I would do it, but I don't see anything wrong with the logic here.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Would you like to add your method as well?

Comment: Your attempt is correct, but from my point of view you should argue more precisely at the essential step of your proof. Why does $\sum a_n^2 <A$ imply that $\sum \frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n^2} <A$? In my opinion, this is the crucial point here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this with the question you asked earlier. I think it has been deleted. Note that $\frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n^2}\leq a_n^2$ for every $n$.

Thus $$ \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n^2}\leq \sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)^2<\infty$$

In the second inequality, I used an estimate you asked for in another question, essentially;  namely $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\right)^2$.

Comment: Thank you, I will add that justification to the answer as well!

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt is fine. You can also argue as follows. Since $a_n^2/(1 + a_n^2) \le |a_n|/2$ for all $n$ (using the identity $1 + x^2 \ge 2|x|$) and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty |a_n|/2$ converges (since $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$ is absolutely convergent), the result follows by the comparison test.

Comment: Thank you! Got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

From some point on, it must be that $|a_n| < 1$. Then $a_n^2 \leq |a_n|$. And $\frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n^2} \leq a_n^2.$ Hence, it converges by comparison test.